# How to change the numbering style of theorems based on the section number using amsthm?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, amsthm

I am using amsthm for theorems, propositions, and so on. But I altered the section numbering style so that it's '§1 First Section', hence my theorems are numbered (since I base them on sections) 'Proposition §1.1' or similar. How can I change this behaviour to just the numbers without '§', but also without having to change my sectioning style again?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\addtokomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\S\arabic{section}}

\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]

\begin{document}
\chapter{Prerequisites}
\section{First Section}
\begin{prop}
Blub
\end{prop}
\end{document}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
\renewcommand{\theprop}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{prop}}
```

Comment: Hello @cmhughes, and thank you for your answer. I can't test it right now, but I'll do it first thing tomorrow. One question: Is \theprop something that will be defined by amsthm automatically once I define \newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section] (i.e., there are similar \the... commands for my other theorem environments as well)?

Comment: @Randal'Thor yep :)

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\makeatletter 
‎\renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{\S‎ 
{\csname ‎the#1\endcsname}‎} 
\makeatother ‎‎‎
\addtokomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]
\begin{document}
\chapter{Prerequisites}
\section{First Section}
\begin{prop}
Blub
\end{prop}
‎\end{document}‎‎
```

Comment: This would add "§" also to subsections (if numbered).